# Python convert an invalid json api response to dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, string, dataframe

I am basically calling a splunk api to fetch the output in json, but by default the result is not in a proper json format.

This is the output which I get from the api

```
{"preview":false,"lastrow":true}\n',
 '{"preview":true,"offset":0,"lastrow":true,"result”:{“user”:”abc1213”,”ip":"10.1.1.1","path”:”/home/search/“,”url_status”:”200”,”count":"7"}}\n{"preview":true,"offset":0,"lastrow":true,"result":{"user”:”abc1213”,”ip”:”10.1.1.1”,”path”:”/browse/contract/payment”,”url_status":"400","count":"7"}}\n{"preview":false,"offset":0,"lastrow":true,"result":{"user”:”abc”123,”ip”:”10.1.1.1”,”path”:”/home/data/contact“,”url_status”:”200”,”count":"7"}}\n'
```

Here the response type is str, I am not sure how to convert it and append the results in nice format, where I can have columns like user | ip | path | url_status

```
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=safe_payload, verify=False)
    return response.text
```

I have tried adding the missing quotes to make the response like json, but still json.loads doesn't works.

Comment: if you would have `'` at the beginning then it would look like CSV with JSON in every column and you could first convert to list using module `csv` and later use `json` for every element. Eventually add `[ ]` to string to creat list which you could read with json and later use `for`- loop to use json again with every element separatelly.

Comment: or maybe you don't get JSON but miltiline-JSON (JSONL) and you should every line run with `json.loads` separatelly.

Comment: @furas my research show that the splunk response is invalid json by default. when I am checking the type of the variable it is "str" but it contains the json like format. this link contains the full code 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71852278/append-result-json-to-dataframe-pandas)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: code in link runs `requests` many times and every request gives one string but you put them on list and later you have list with many results - and you should work with every result separatelly. And if it really sends JSON then you should use `response.json()` instead of `response.text`

Comment: and it seems it send it as `multiline-JSON` so you have to split text on `\n` and every line convert with `json.loads()`separatelly

Comment: I see also some wrong chars `” “` - but this can be resolved with `.replace()`. PRoblem makes response with `"user":"abc"123` which is not correct value. You should send this problem to splunk. OR if you generate responses then you should check code which sends responses. you chould also check what you have in CSV - maybe you have this problem in file data.

Comment: "user":"abc"123 : this one is my typo issue

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution, if someone out there needs.  The code will transform the splunk api invalid json to pandas dataframe into rows and columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import urllib3
from base64 import b64encode
import urllib.parse
from csv import reader


urllib3.disable_warnings()

data=[]
output1 = pd.DataFrame()

def fetch_data_using_userid(userid):
    url = "https://localhost:8000/services/search/jobs/export"
    payload = {
        'search': f'search  earliest = -40h index=* user_id="{userid}" | stats count by user user_ip ',
        'output_mode':'json'
    }
    safe_payload = urllib.parse.urlencode(payload)

    userAndPass = b64encode(b"admin:pass").decode("ascii")
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Basic %s' % userAndPass,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=safe_payload, verify=False)
    return response.text


# open file in read mode
with open('/Users/Downloads/user_data.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    # pass the file object to reader() to get the reader object
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    if header is not None:
        # Iterate over each row in the csv using reader object
        for row in csv_reader:
            # row variable is a list that represents a row in csv
            print(row)
            response_text = fetch_data_using_userid(row[0])
            data = response_text
            with open('data.txt', 'w') as wf:
                wf.write(data)
            with open('data.txt') as rf:
                for entry in rf:
                    LDict = json.loads(entry)
                    output1 = output1.append(LDict,ignore_index=True)
            print(response_text)
#  result1 = pd.json_normalize(output1['result'])
```

Comment: you could use directly `for entry in response_text.split('\n')`  without writing to file.

Comment: @furas when I use it, I get this `JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)`. That's why I thought of creating a dummy text.